# AutoHotkey script to open start menu with CMD+Space on Mac keyboard on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, autohotkey

I'm usually a Mac user, therefore I am accustomed to, and prefer, Mac style shortcuts.

I'm using an Apple keyboard on my work PC, and I've installed SharpKeys to swap CTRL and CMD keys around.

Now, I've installed AutoHotkey in the hopes that I can make CMD+Space (prior to swapped CTRL and CMD) open the start menu.

I've tried writing a small script for it, but it just doesn't work, I can't figure out why.

Here's the script:

```
^space::
    Send, {LWin Down}{LWin Up}
Return
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
^space:: Send ^{esc}
```

or

```
^Space::Send, {Ctrl up}{LWin}
```

It's been a while since I used AHK, but thanks for reminding me about it! I pulled the top one from an old text file I had in my dropbox. The second code was found online. Someone said the Ctrl in the macro may be interfering with the code, so the second code releases the Ctrl key first.

Comment: Happy to help. I always forget the Ctrl+esc opens the start menu. That's why I used an AHK on an old laptop. the Win key went bad, had to find a workaround.